# Какой LicenseCode нужен что бы отправлять почту?

Tags: delphi, email

Есть такой код для отправки почты:

```
    oSmtp := TMail.Create(Application);
    oSmtp.LicenseCode := 'TryIt';
    oSmtp.FromAddr := 'sender@mail.ru';
    oSmtp.AddRecipientEx('reciver@gmail.com', 0);
    oSmtp.Subject := 'theme';
    oSmtp.BodyText := 'text';
    oSmtp.ServerAddr := 'smtp.mail.ru';
    oSmtp.UserName := 'sender@mail.ru';
    oSmtp.Password := 'password';
    oSmtp.ConnectType := ConnectTryTLS;
    if oSmtp.SendMail() = 0 then
    begin
    
    end else
    begin
    
    end;
```

По началу всё нормально работало, а сейчас во второй строке выдаёт ошибку "Trial Version Expired!".
Где бы я не смотрел примеры кода, используют `oSmtp.LicenseCode := 'TryIt';`.
Подскажите, что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0):

Вы используете демо-версию коммерческого компонента для отправки почты EASendMail SMTP Component.

Соответственно, по окончании демо-периода вам надо этот компонент купить [Purchase EASendMail SMTP Component](https://www.emailarchitect.net/easendmail/buy.aspx), после чего вам вышлют ключ, который вы и сможете подставить вместо `TryIt`.

Comment: знаете ли Вы бесплатный аналог?

Comment: Пункт 4: http://delphiprogrammingdiary.blogspot.com/2014/12/how-to-send-email-in-delphi.html